# How do I configure Pentaho Kettle repository to folder and/or SVN repository containing Kettle ETL scripts?

Tags: java, repository, etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm a newbie to Kettle and need some help setting it up properly.  I'm trying to point Kettle at an SVN repository.  For now, I just have the following folders.

```
D:\ETL\data-integration\
D:\ETL\.kettle\
D:\ETL\Kettle-custom\
D:\ETL\scripts\
D:\ETL\logs\
```

The data-integration folder was extracted from pdi-ce-4.3.0-stable.zip.

In D:\ETL.kettle\repositories.xml, I'm pointing to D:\ETL\Kettle-custom\

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repositories>
<repository>    
    <id>KettleFileRepository</id>
    <name>3</name>
    <description>custom_import</description>
    <base_directory>D:\ETL\Kettle-custom</base_directory>
    <read_only>N</read_only>
    <hides_hidden_files>N</hides_hidden_files>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

I have an SVN repository set up called "etl" and a project named "kettle".

```
https://mydomain:8443/svn/etl/kettle/trunk
```

At this point, I get this popup, but I'm not sure what the "admin" password is, or what to do after this point.  I'd first like to connect Kettle to this folder.  But I'd also like to connect it to SVN if that's possible.  Anything you can explain to me would be beneficial.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about the term "Repository." The PDI Repository is not a SVN repository it's a custom home grown database repository.

So you need to click on the + button to add a repository and enter some database details.  The password is just admin/admin IIRC once you've created your repo.

You dont need to use a repository though. If you want to store your files in SVN and then open those files then just cancel this dialog.

Comment: I have a repositories.xml file from a working system.  I'm just moving the code to a different server.  When I moved all of the Kettle code (data-integration, scripts, .kettle files, etc...), the repositories.xml file was already in there, but when I launch Spoon on the new server, it didn't see it there.  How can I make it read an already existing repositories.xml file so I don't have to create them from scratch.

Comment: ah. The repositories.xml just contains your database connection info, i.e. hardly anything. Anyway put it into your ~/.kettle directory and it should pick it up.

Comment: There were references to the path within a few different places.  Spoon.bat and our Kitchen_*.bat scripts had references to this repository.

Answer (score 0):

After launched spoon have you checked the repository is connected or not if not connected then connect then able to see repositiers.xml file in your shared location